# Sapply returning matrix instead of vector

Tags: r

I have a function

```
myfunction <- function(x,y){
      x+y
}
```

and I want to pass x and y vectors to it and get a vector of their same length which is just the sum of their elements.

For some reason when I use

```
 sapply(x,myfunction,y)
```

I get a matrix instead of a vector. What am I doing wrong? Am I using the wrong function?

Example:

```
x = c(1,2,3,4) 
y = c(2,4,6,8)
sapply(x,myfunction,y)
>     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
      [1,]    3    4    5    6
      [2,]    5    6    7    8
      [3,]    7    8    9   10
      [4,]    9   10   11   12
```

when my desired output is a vector (3,6,9,12).

Comment: You need just `x + y` and not loop over each element i.e. `myfunction(x, y)`  If you need to use apply functions, use `mapply(myfunction, x, y)`.  The `sapply` looped over each element of 'x and is adding all the elements of y instead of correspnding elements

Comment: Your `sapply` basically does this: `cbind(myfunction(x[1], y), myfunction(x[2], y), myfunction(x[3], y), myfunction(x[4], y))`

Comment: @RobertHacken / akrun : Got it. Had a different impression from the documentation, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arithmetic operations are vectorized, so the function can be applied directly

```
 myfunction(x, y)
[1]  3  6  9 12
```

---

With `sapply`, the `X` input argument is used by `x` thus, each element of `x` is looped while the `y` remains the whole vector, thus when we apply the function, it returns the output with the same length as 'y' for each element of 'x' and also as `sapply` use `simplify = TRUE` by default, it returns a matrix.  If we need to use *apply function (and assuming the example is a simplified case), then we may need either `mapply` or `Map` which does loop over the corresponding elements of both inputs and apply the function on each element separately

```
mapply(myfunction, x, y)
[1]  3  6  9 12
```